# How to Set fixed Column/Row Definitions in code and use them in DesignView

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I'd like to have Grids with fixed amount of column and rows. 80 columns and 24 rows for example.
In design view, the user must not be able to change the column and row definitions but he must be able to insert controls into the cells.

Design View should look like [this http://imageshack.us/f/29/coldefs.png](http://imageshack.us/f/29/coldefs.png)

I tried to subclass Grid and set the Column and Row Definitions inside the constructor, but then the cells did not show up in DesignView at all.

Can this be done?

Comment: Did u try Grid.Initialized event handlder and tried to add your RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in it?

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `Grid` to add the dependency properties `Rows` and `Columns` and in the PropertyChanged callback you update the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` accordingly.

To get GridLines in design time you can add a `Border` to each cell in the `Loaded` event if you are in Design Mode (`DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == true`)

Use it like this

```
<local:FixedSizeGrid Rows="24"
                     Columns="80"
                     Background="#E8E8E8">
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
</local:FixedSizeGrid>
```

And the output in the designer will look like below. In runtime you'll get no `Borders`.

[image]

**Edit**
The Children Property (which is the `ContentProperty` for `Grid`) keeps getting reset in the framework when adding and removing elements. This means that the Grid-Borders get wiped clean as well and there is no way to be notified about this as far as I can tell. To work around this I had to change the `ContentProperty` of `FixedSizeGrid` to a new DP which in turn updates both Children and the DesignMode Grid-Borders.

There are several optimizations that can be made, clearing and readding the Grid-Borders everytime for example. Anyway, here is the updated code. It should work in the designer now, perhaps a little slow if many rows/columns are set but this can probably be fixed with some optimizations.

**FixedSizeGrid**

```
[ContentProperty("ContentChildren")]
public class FixedSizeGrid : Grid
{
    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rows",
                                    typeof(int),
                                    typeof(FixedSizeGrid),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(24, RowsPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns",
                                    typeof(int),
                                    typeof(FixedSizeGrid),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(80, ColumnsPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContentChildren",
                                    typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>),
                                    typeof(FixedSizeGrid),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<UIElement>()));

    #endregion // Dependency Properties

    #region Properties

    private static void RowsPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FixedSizeGrid fixedSizeGrid = sender as FixedSizeGrid;
        fixedSizeGrid.UpdateRowDefinitions();
    }
    private static void ColumnsPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FixedSizeGrid fixedSizeGrid = sender as FixedSizeGrid;
        fixedSizeGrid.UpdateColumnDefinitions();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> ContentChildren
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ContentChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value); }
    }
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Fields

    private List<Border> m_designTimeBorders;

    #endregion //Fields

    #region Constructor

    public FixedSizeGrid()
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == true)
        {
            m_designTimeBorders = new List<Border>();
        }

        SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
        Loaded += FixedSizeGrid_Loaded;
        ContentChildren.CollectionChanged += ContentChildren_CollectionChanged;
    }

    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Event Handlers

    private void FixedSizeGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRowDefinitions();
        UpdateColumnDefinitions();
    }

    private void ContentChildren_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in e.NewItems)
            {
                RemoveFromParent(element);
                Children.Add(element);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in e.OldItems)
            {
                Children.Remove(element);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            Children.Clear();
        }
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == true)
        {
            AddDesignTimeBorders();
        }
    }

    #endregion // Event Handlers

    #region Private Methods

    private void RemoveFromParent(UIElement element)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = element;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is FixedSizeGrid))
        {
            parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        if (parent != null)
        {
            (parent as FixedSizeGrid).Children.Remove(element);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateRowDefinitions()
    {
        while (RowDefinitions.Count > Rows && RowDefinitions.Count > 0)
            RowDefinitions.Remove(RowDefinitions[RowDefinitions.Count-1]);
        while (RowDefinitions.Count < Rows)
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == true)
        {
            AddDesignTimeBorders();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateColumnDefinitions()
    {
        while (ColumnDefinitions.Count > Columns && ColumnDefinitions.Count > 0)
            ColumnDefinitions.Remove(ColumnDefinitions[ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1]);
        while (ColumnDefinitions.Count < Columns)
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == true)
        {
            AddDesignTimeBorders();
        }
    }

    private void AddDesignTimeBorders()
    {
        RemoveDesignTimeBorders();
        for (int row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
            {
                Border designTimeBorder = new Border();
                designTimeBorder.Tag = "DesignTimeBorder";
                designTimeBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(154, 191, 229));
                designTimeBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0,0,1,1);
                Grid.SetRow(designTimeBorder, row);
                Grid.SetColumn(designTimeBorder, column);
                m_designTimeBorders.Add(designTimeBorder);
            }
        }
        foreach (Border designTimeBorder in m_designTimeBorders)
        {
            Children.Add(designTimeBorder);
        }
    }
    private void RemoveDesignTimeBorders()
    {
        foreach (Border designTimeBorder in m_designTimeBorders)
        {
            Children.Remove(designTimeBorder);
        }
        m_designTimeBorders.Clear();
    }

    #endregion // Private Methods
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I can't see the grid in the Designer once I add a child and I can't change the grids children width/height/column/columnspan/etc in the design view but I'll give it another try next week. The grid does exist though.
Thanks

Comment: @Markus: I have no problem using `ColumnSpan` etc. The rows and columns are "*" sized though, I'll update the code with an option to set it. I see what you mean with the grid disappearing, the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` are removed for some reason if you add and remove children a couple of times. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Markus: Updated my answer, the problems should be solved now. Try it out

Comment: The grid shows up fine now. 

Does moving or resizing the children in design view work for you?
If I try it, the childrens width and height are reduced to zero.

Comment: @Markus: Yes, I can't find any scenario where it breaks for me. Can you give me a specific scenario where this happends? What version of Visual Studio are you using and what operation system? I've tried it on Windows 7 (VS2010 with SP 1) and Windows XP (VS2010).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ShowGridLines` property to true if you want to see the cell or squares